# Get Agent Response DialogFlow

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dialogflow-es

So i have made a basic agent on dialogflow and a simple web page that lets the user insert a question. I have also made a very simple node server that takes the question made by the user. 
Now i would like to programmatically feed this question into my agent and get the agent response based on the question made. How do i do this?

THIS IS THE WEB PAGE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://127.0.0.1:80/question" method='get'>
  Question:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="questionValue">
  <br>
 <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

THIS IS THE SERVER

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


//handle get req on /question
app.get('/question', function (req, res) {    
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

    //process
    var q = req.query.questionValue;
    //write response
    res.write(q);
    //send response
    res.end();
});


//listen in a specific port
app.listen((process.env.PORT || 80));

//check status
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:80/');
```

Comment: check this node js sdk https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client